# Best numerical simulations of Sun's magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, resource-recommendations, plasma-physics, sun, solar-wind

I was trying to find some simulations of the Sun's magnetic field. Which ones are the most accurate to date?

Comment: I think this might get closed since you are asking for a recommendation and we typically do not do that.  But it is also not clear if you are asking for a product that makes this simulation or more info about numerical methods that you could use to make your own.  Please elaborate in your question.  I will flag this for closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was trying to find some simulations of the Sun's magnetic field.

A good place to start is at the [Community Coordinated Modeling Center](https://ccmc.gsfc.nasa.gov/about.php) or CCMC.  They have a list of models available models, not just solar, at https://ccmc.gsfc.nasa.gov/modelweb/.

> Which ones are the most accurate to date?

I do not think this has a good answer because it's not clear what is meant by accurate here.  There are different models for different tasks.  Each one does well for the task/phenomena it was designed to approximate.  None of them do well on every front mostly because of computational constraints and limited observations of the boundary conditions (e.g., we don't have in situ measurements in the [photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere)).